# How can I correctly align the tops of these divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a webpage containing 2 sets of divs. The first set of divs should be fixed in position and aligned to the left of the page. The second set of divs contains the main content of the webpage, and should be scrollable.

To do this, Ive created the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="height: 1500px">

<div style="position: fixed; display: inline;">

    <div style="border-style: solid; width: 250px; margin: 15px; padding: 15px;"><h2>Add Media</h2></div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; width: 250px; margin: 15px; padding: 15px;"><h2>Add Media</h2></div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; width: 250px; margin: 15px; padding: 15px;"><h2>Add Media</h2></div>

</div>


<div style="margin-left: 350px">

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="border-style: solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
        <h1>POST</h1>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This code performs as I'd hope it to, except the top of the first div from each section does not align. How can I fix this?

Also, is my method for creating a webpage of this style correct?

Comment: Make yourself a favor and move the CSS to a stylesheet.

Comment: `Also, is my method for creating a webpage of this style correct?` No. You should be using `classes` for the styles to be scalable. The way it's done now is nearly static.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Where can I learn about classes?

Comment: @JohnSmith Check out classes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). Also, consider reading [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) about styling types first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your code:

HTML -

```
<body>
 <div class="addMedia">
   <div class="addMediaDivs">
     <h2>Add Media</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="addMediaDivs">
     <h2>Add Media</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="addMediaDivs">
     <h2>Add Media</h2>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="postBlocks">
   <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
    <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="postDivs">
     <h1>POST</h1>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS -

```
body{
  height: 1500px;
}

.addMedia{
  position: fixed; 
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.addMediaDivs{
  border-style: solid; 
  width: 250px; 
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}

.postBlocks{
  margin-left: 350px;
}

.postDivs{
  border-style: solid; 
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  padding: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Essentially, what you've done isn't the best industry standard to style your code. You may want to keep your css in a separate .css file, and just use classes/ id's in your html. You had assigned different padding/margins to both the divs. Hence, the tops weren't aligned.

You can read more more about effective CSS styling techniques here - https://css-tricks.com/css-style-guides/ , https://hackhands.com/70-Expert-Ideas-For-Better-CSS-Coding/ , http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/20-useful-css-tips-for-beginners/.

If you want to see how  to get better at styling via an example, check the code here which I reformatted per your needs - http://plnkr.co/edit/IGAF8HZAIegJeMU1inzd?p=preview

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help